# Problem in Displaying/Hiding Visual based upon a Slicer value, using Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem where I have to hide a visual and show another visual based upon Slicer Selection. I followed this tutorial: [https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/#:~:text=Click%20on%2...](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%2...).

My problem is,

1. I have a slicer for Capacity.
2. If a user Selects "All" Capacity, then it should show a Bar Graph with **Capacity on X-Axis**.
3. If a user selects **any particular capacity**, then the bar graph shown should have **Operation on X-axis**

To solve this issue, I created two Bar Graphs. I created a Measure that checks whether **capacity is filtered or not**,

```
Is Capacity Selected = 
    IF(
        ISFILTERED('Main Sheet'[Capacity]), 
        1, 
        2
    )
```

And added this to both Graph **Visual Filters.**

The problem I am facing is when **I select 2**, the Bar Graph with Operation at X-Axis disappears (as expected), but the bar graph with Capacity at X-Axis **does not show**. I also added a card to check the value of Measure and it's also 2, which means that the bar graph with Capacity at X-Axis should show when I select "All" from the Capacity Filter.

Even more interestingly, if **I change the X-Axis to any attribute other than Capacity**, then this bar graph works totally fine.

Can anyone help me out in this? How can I show the Visual of Bar Graph containing Capacity at X-Axis, whenever "All" is selected from Capacity Slicer.

**Here's the Power BI Workbook that you can download and use: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8YAYZ8spOLKlA9HLE1coN17mnDyTA1w/view?usp=sharing**

I also uploaded a small video on Youtube showing the expected behavior of what I am doing and where is it causing the problem,

https://youtu.be/1-teUkPKZ8Q

As you can see, when using **BillingPool** (any attribute other than Capacity), I get the expected Results. But as soon as I select Capacity on X-Axis, the same behavior doesn't happen.

Comment: Is this an unpaid consulting job? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that could potentially help other users too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the DAX is being evaluated. It is being evaluated per data point. Convert the chart to a table and place the measure in a column to see what I mean.

To achieve your desired behaviour, create a new table as follows named Selection:

[image]

Change your measure:

```
Is Capacity Selected = 
    IF(
        SELECTEDVALUE(Selection[Column1]) == "First Capacity" || SELECTEDVALUE(Selection[Column1]) == "Second Capacity"  , 
        1, 
        2
    )
```

Change the slicer to use the new table you just created and everything should work as desired.

Comment: Oh God! Finally understood why DAX was causing the issue. Never thought of converting it into a table and then seeing the results. Thank you so much for this amazing tip! I solved it by using your approach of creating a new table, thank you!